# How to select 1 column value based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table

| Date | trial | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | false | 100 |
| 2020-12-10 | true | 200 |
| 2020-12-11 | false | 150 |
| 2020-12-11 | true | 350 |

I want result

| Date | total | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | 300 | 100 |
| 2020-12-11 | 500 | 150 |

Where value1 is the value when trial=false.
what is the SQL query to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date, sum(value),
       sum(case when trial = 'false' then value end) as value1
from t
group by date;
```

Note:  If your database support boolean values and `trial` is boolean, then:

```
       sum(case when trial then value end) as value1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cnoditional aggregation:

```
select date, sum(value) as total,
    sum(case when trial = 'false' then value else 0 end) as value1
from mytable
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case statement in select clause:

SELECT
...,
case when ColumnA > x
then ColumnA
else ColumnB
end as C
from ...

for more details visit :  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx](http://%20http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)